# How to get the "value" of a FilteringSelect <select> in dojo?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dojo

I am using dijit.form.FilteringSelect to provide a way to select values from a <select>. The problem is, when using dojo, the label is returned instead of the value of the s.

For example:
`<select name="test" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect">

 <option value="1">One</option>

 <option value="2">Two</option>

</select>`
Dojo is returning the literal "one" if that option is selected, instead of the value for that option, "1". The same is true for "two" and "2".

If dojo is removed from this element, the value is returned as expected.

Comment: What do you mean "dojo is returning the value".  Or you posting this form?  If so how, via a normal HTTP post or a dojo XHR request, or are you trying to read the value by using dojo.getValue via a JS.  A more complete set of code would be required to help.

Comment: It behaves exactly as mctom987 says. That could be because Swigley edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found out that dojo creates 2 elements. One using the name, which contains the value which uses the NAME of the element, and another which contains the label for the option, which uses the ID of the element. Since I was using document.getElementById(), this was returning the wrong value. Using the value from the name provides the correct result.

Comment: Yes, so you need to use the dijit API that Swingley states. Using document.getElementByid or jquery will yield different results.

Answer (score 17):

The dojo way to do this would be to use dijit.byId('yourDijitId').attr().

To get the value you want:

```
dijit.byId('yourDijitId').attr('value');
```

To get the value displayed in the filtering select:

```
dijit.byId('yourDijitId').attr('displayedValue');
```

*EDIT*:  attr() was deprecated at 1.5, [at 1.5 and beyond, use get()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/releasenotes/1.5.html#new-get-set-and-deprecated-attr)

Comment: attr is now deprecated. You should use get instead. Eg. dijit.byId('yourDijitId').get('value');

Answer (score 8):

To get the Value of **dijit.form.FilteringSelect**

```
dijit.byId('yourId').get('value');
```

To get the displayedValue of **dijit.form.FilteringSelect**

```
dijit.byId('yourId').get('displayedValue');
```

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same issue and came up with this solution.

```
var optVal = dijit.byId("yourDijitId").item.value;
```

The FilteringsSelect widget puts the "Display Value" in both the `displayValue` and `value` properties.  The only way that I have found to get the option value is to go through the `item` property which lists the selected options properties.

Answer (score 0):

For fellow Googlers out there trying to find the SELECTED OBJECT in FilteringSelect:

```
dijit.byId("yourDijitId").item
```

refers to the selected item, in case you need access to the object's other properties.

(hat tip to Bitwize for pointin to right direction with `dijit.byId("yourDijitId").item.value`)