# dojo.byId() works but dijit.byId() doesn't

Tags: dojo

I have a select field with id `appointment_stylist_id`. For some reason, the first one of these returns my element but the second one returns `undefined`:

```
  console.log(dojo.byId('appointment_stylist_id'));
  console.log(dijit.byId('appointment_stylist_id'));
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because `dojo.byId` does what you want (find a DOM element with a particular ID), and `dijit.byId` doesn't do that.

> `dijit.byId` is a function for looking up a specific widget by its assigned name (id). This function is similar to `dojo.byId` but whereas `dojo.byId` returns DOMNodes, `dijit.byId` returns a JavaScript object that is the instance of the widget.
>
> ...
>
> `dijit.byId` and `dojo.byId` are often confused, particularly by first time users. This function should be used when you wish to obtain a direct handle the the JavaScript object instance of your widget and access functions of that widget.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/byId.html

#### See also

[What the difference between dojo.byId and dijit.byId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159113/what-the-difference-between-dojo-byid-and-dijit-byid)

Comment: Okay. Maybe this should be a separate question, but is there any easy way, then, to get the selected value of a select input? In jQuery, you just do `$("#appointment_stylist_id").val()`.

Comment: [Most of the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923#4652402), `dojo.byId('appointment_stylist_id').value` will work. Are you also using Dijit? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850050/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-filteringselect-select-in-dojo)

Comment: `.value` worked. Thanks. I'm not using Dijit. (I'd seen that question already but it didn't seem to apply.)

Comment: If you prefer the chaining thing, you can do `dojo.query("#appointment_stylist_id").attr("value")` and even `var $ = dojo.query` :-)

Comment: Wasn't use of attr() deprecated in 1.5 - In favour of the get/set helper methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
dojo.byId("appointment_stylist_id");
```

Returns the element.

```
dijit.byId("appointment_stylist_id");
```

Returns the widget.

Using dijit.byId also you can get the value of the element like:

```
dijit.byId("appointment_stylist_id").getValue();
```

Comment: `getValue()` is in most cases **deprecated**, use `get("value")` in stead.